# how can i monitor a list of numbers with a less or more than (value) and perform action if the value is in range?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, 64-bit, monitor

i am trying to write a win 10 batch script which monitors a output of numbers in csv, 5 lines like `111.07 112.56 123.66` etc. The output happens every 60sec.
(Optionally i can store that in a `log.txt` and call that in the script)
Also I want to have the output numbers in absolute values without decimals.
Then do a Less or equal than or greater than ... (`LEQ 100` and `GEQ 140` -> right?). `If` in range `then` immediately reboot `shutdown -r -f -t 00` else `go to :start` again.

I have to admit i have no clue what i am doing and everything i tried just immediately exits the script, even when do a pause or timeout after every step.

EDIT: Here is what i have so far.

```
:start
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%i IN ('nvidia-smi.exe --format=csv,nounits,noheader --query-gpu=power.draw') do (SET var=%%i%)
echo %%var%
if %%var% LEQ 100 (echo reboot) else (goto :start)
If %%var% GEQ 140 (echo reboot) else (goo :start)
```

The First line should store the 5 output lines of (‘nvidia-Smi.exe ….‘) in the variable var.

Output of Nvidia-smi.exe:

```
117.00
123.34
116.77
128.65
119.45
```

The second should do the if else comparison and reboot (for now just echo) I do not understand how i can build the if else into the for loop.
The Nvidia-smi.exe seems not to be executed but just to be printed, but when i run the command in a cmd it executes. The commas get removed between cvs,Mounties,noheader
Also i do not understand how to not repeat myself in the if leq … else ….

Output:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\monitor.bat

C:\Users\admin>FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %i IN ('nvidia-smi.exe --format csv nounits noheader --query-gpu power.draw') do (SET var=%i )

C:\Users\admin>(SET var=nvidia-smi.exe --format csv nounits noheader --query-gpu power.draw )

C:\Users\admin>echo %var
%var
Syntaxerror.

C:\Users\admin>    if %varstart)
```

Comment: A shoot into sky just for __FOR__ demonstration: `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('nvidia-smi.exe --format csv nounits noheader --query-gpu power.draw') do for %%J in (%%I) do if %%~nJ LEQ 100 (echo %%J is less or equal 100) else if %%~nJ GEQ 100 (echo %%J is greater or equal 140) else %%J is between 100 and 140`

Comment: If i run your demonstrated command, the Nvidia-Smi.exe tells me that the arguments are invalid and i should use Nvidia-smi.exe -h.
The loop is then done for ‚Nvidia-smi.exe -h‘ as text.

`C:\Users\admin>if -h' LEQ 100 (echo -h' is less or equal 100 )  else if -h' GEQ 100 (echo -h' is greater or equal 140 )  else -h' is between 100 and 140`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Mofi,

with your demonstration i managed to get it right.

```
:begin
@echo off
Timeout 57
if exist log.txt del log.txt 
nvidia-smi.exe --format=csv,nounits,noheader --query-gpu=power.limit --filename=log.txt
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%I in (log.txt) do for %%J in (%%I) do if %%~nJ LEQ 100 (echo %%J is less or equal 100 && shutdown /r /f /t 60) else if %%~nJ GEQ 140 (echo %%J is greater or equal 140 && shutdown /r /f /t 60) else (echo %%J% is between 100 and 140)
goto :begin
```

Output:

```
117.00 is between 100 and 140
148.00 is greater or equal 140
126.00 is between 100 and 140
96.00 is Less or equal 100
127.00 is between 100 and 140
```